# Limit of a differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Have $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, differentiable at some $x$. Let $(u_n), (v_n)$ be sequences s.t. $u_n \leq x \leq v_n$ for all $n$, $u_n \neq v_n$ and $u_n,v_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Prove that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{g(v_n)-g(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}$$

exists.

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume first for simplicity that $u_n<x<v_n$ for all $n$.
Show that $\frac{g(v_n)-g(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}$ is a convex combination of $\frac{g(v_n)-g(x)}{v_n-x}$ and $\frac{g(u_n)-g(x)}{u_n-x}$, hence the sequence is squeezed as follows:
$$ \min\left\{\frac{g(v_n)-g(x)}{v_n-x},\frac{g(u_n)-g(x)}{u_n-x}\right\}\le  \frac{g(v_n)-g(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}\le \max\left\{\frac{g(v_n)-g(x)}{v_n-x},\frac{g(u_n)-g(x)}{u_n-x}\right\}$$
Then note that it doesn't hurt if (only one of!) $\frac{g(v_n)-g(x)}{v_n-x}$, $\frac{g(u_n)-g(x)}{u_n-x}$ is not defined (beacuse $x=u_n$ or $x=v_n$) cause in that case $\frac{g(v_n)-g(u_n)}{v_n-u_n}$ simply equals the other fraction.

Comment: What do you mean by a convex combination? Something like t*(first term) + (1-t)*(second term)? I don't know how to do the first step :/