# Sequence $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ satisfy $a_n \to c, b_n \to c $

Tags: calculus

Sequence $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ satisfy $a_n \to c, b_n \to c $ , and $a_n\lt c \lt b_n $. $f'(c) $ exists.
Prove $$\frac{f(a_n)-f(b_n)}{a_n-b_n}\to f'(c)$$
I have a rough idea like this,
$$\frac{f(a_n)-f(b_n)}{a_n-b_n}=\frac{f(a_n)-f(c)-(f(b_n)-f(c))}{a_n-b_n}=\frac{f(a_n)-f(c)}{a_n-b_n}-\frac{f(b_n)-f(c)}{a_n-b_n}=\frac{f'(c)\cdot(a_n-c)}{a_n-b_n}-\frac{f'(c)\cdot(b_n-c)}{a_n-b_n}=f'(c)$$
But obviously not strictly. So how to do this thing strictly?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/817944/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : $$\frac{f(a_n)-f(b_n)}{a_n-b_n} = \frac{
 f(a_n)-f(c)}{a_n-c} \frac{a_n-c}{a_n-b_n} -
 \frac{f(b_n) -f(c)}{b_n-c}\frac{b_n-c}{a_n-b_n} $$

Step 2 : $$\lim\ (
 X_n Y_n - X_n'Z_n)=\lim\ X_n \cdot \lim\ (Y_n-Z_n)$$ where $
 \lim\ X_n=\lim\ X_n'$ and $|Z_n|\leq 1$.

Proof : $ X_n Y_n - X_n'Z_n =
 X_n (Y_n - Z_n) + (X_n-X_n')Z_n$